# Use/ modify Vuex state directly in template

Tags: vue.js, vuex, mutation

I think I have a misunderstanding of Vue + Vuex.

I have a Vuex state which contains a filter for a list. Each filter item in the list can be marked as selected. BUT - the Vuex state should only be modified through a modifier when an apply button is clicked, so that other components can react to the change.

For example, the list would reload data depending on the selected filters. When the state updates, the component should also be updated.

I have created a CodePen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzEJWP?editors=1010

https://jsfiddle.net/rxqu7ame/

```js
Vue.component('filter-item', {
    template: ` <div>
            <!--{{item.color}} ({{item.selected}}) <button @click="item.selected = !item.selected">toggle</button>-->
            {{item.color}} ({{isSelected}}) <button @click="isSelected = !isSelected">toggle</button>
          </div>`,
    data: function () {
        return {
            isSelected: this.item.selected
        }
    },
    computed: {
        /*isSelected : function(){
          return this.item.selected;
        }*/
    },

    props: ['item']
});
```

I ran into different problems:

1. When I toggle the `selected` property directly within the `filter-item` template, the Vuex state is also updated (which I don't want).
2. So I tried to initialize a data property (local to the component) with the state, that way only the data variable `isSelected` would be updated. When I pressed the "apply" button, the Vuex state would then be updated (later I would use a mutation). So far, so good. But now, the `isSelected` property would not automatically update when the state changed.
3. If I use a computed property, `isSelected` could not be changed in the click event (since it's read only).

What is the right way to achieve my desired scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/guanzo/pen/xpzrMm?editors=0010

I've ran into this sort of situation before, and found it easiest to add a "temporary" variable next to the "actual" variable in the store. The "actual" variable is `selected`, and the "temporary" variable is `tempSelected`". `tempSelected` will be updated when the user toggles a color, and `selected` will be updated when you "apply to store".

Here's what the default store state looks like

```
filter: [
      {
        color: 'red',
        selected: false,
        tempSelected: false,
      },
      {
        color: 'green',
        selected: false,
        tempSelected: false,
      }      
    ]
```

Here's how to toggle a single color through a mutation. You shouldn't directly update the store through references, always do it through mutations. If you're confused about the computed get/set syntax, look here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

```
Vue.component('filter-item', {
  template: ` <div>
                {{item.color}} ({{item.tempSelected}}) 
<button @click="isSelected = !isSelected">toggle</button>
              </div>`,
  computed: {
     isSelected:{
       get(){
         var filter = this.$store.state.filter.find(filter=>filter.color === this.item.color)
         return filter.tempSelected
       },
       set(value){
         this.$store.commit('updateSelected',{
           color: this.item.color,
           selected: value
         })
       }
     }
  },
```

Here's the store mutation to update a single color.

```
updateSelected(state,payload){
  var filter = state.filter.find(filter=>filter.color===payload.color)
  filter.tempSelected = payload.selected
}
```

Now you have the temp variable storing the user input. To "apply to store", you simply need to set the value of the actual variable, to the value of the temp variable

```
updateFilters(state){
      state.updates++;
      state.filter.forEach(filter=>{
          filter.selected = filter.tempSelected
      })
    },
```

To toggle all values, just flip the current `selected` value. But be sure to keep the `tempSelected` variable in sync.

```
toggleFilters(state){
      state.updates++;
      state.filter.forEach(filter=>{
          filter.selected = !filter.selected
          filter.tempSelected = filter.selected
      })
    },
```

It's now trivial to implement a "cancel changes" features. If a user wishes to undo all their changes, you can set `tempSelected` to the value of `selected`, effectively restoring the state to the last known value.

Answer (score 0):

1) For example, you can add computed property to filter-item and watcher for this property. So, filter-item component will know if vuex changed, and change isSelected property:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    isSelected: this.$store.state.filter[this.index].selected
  }
},
computed: {
  storeSelected: function(){
    return this.$store.state.filter[this.index].selected;
  },
  color: function(){
    return this.$store.state.filter[this.index].color;
  }
},
watch: {
  storeSelected: function(){
    this.isSelected = this.$store.state.filter[this.index].selected;
  }
},
props: ['index']
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/aircrisp/pen/MrXEgd?editors=0010

2)

> The only way to actually change state in a Vuex store is by committing a mutation. https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html

So, if you use mutation to change vuex state - you can subscribe to mutation in filter-item component, for example, after component mounted:

```
mounted: function(){
  this.$store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
     if(mutation === 'changeFilterItem'){
       this.isSelected = state.filter[this.index].selected;
     }
  })
 },
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/aircrisp/pen/MrXEgd?editors=0010 (commented code)